# Segmentation fault after allocating memory for a struct in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct queue
{
    struct node *front;
    struct node *rear;
};

struct queue *q;

void create_queue(struct queue *);
int main()
{
    create_queue(q);

    ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr->data = 42;

    q->front = ptr; <-- here it fails with Sementaion fault

    return 0;
}

void create_queue(struct queue *q)
{
    q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    q->rear = NULL;
    q->front = NULL;
}
```

And this fails on trying to assign ptr to queue front, but if i move the line `q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));` to the main function before `create_queue(q)` everything works well. What the reason the Segmentation fault error depends on the memory allocation position in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following function does not update global variable q.

```
void create_queue(struct queue *q)
{
    q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    q->rear = NULL;
    q->front = NULL;
}
```

It is in fact working with local variable which goes out of scope with subsequent memory leak (and global variable still pointing to some garbage).
you need to define your function this way:

```
void create_queue(struct queue **q)
{
    *q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    *q->rear = NULL;
    *q->front = NULL;
}
```

and call it

```
create_queue(&q);
```

so you should pass address of your variable into the function instead of value.

Comment: Thanks, but to compile we also need to place parenthesis `(*q)->rear = NULL; (*q)->front = NULL;`

Comment: @Dmitrii Instead of setting all fields to NULL, just call `bzero(*q,sizeof(struct queue))` or memset()

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a double pointer `struct queue **q` to `create_queue()`

```
void create_queue(struct queue **q)
{
    *q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    (*q)->rear = NULL;
    (*q)->front = NULL;
}
```

This is because you want to update the pointer `q` itself, not what it points to.